# How can I copy some strings from file to another using c programming

Tags: c, string, file, copy, multiple-columns

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
  

int main()
{

    FILE* ptr = fopen("data.txt","r");
    char filename[100];
    if (ptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("no such file.");
        return 0;
    }
 
    char buf[100];
    while (fscanf(ptr,"%*s %*s %s ",buf)==1)
        printf("%s\n", buf);



printf("Create a file \n");
    scanf("%s", filename);
  
    fptr2 = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (fptr2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file %s \n", filename);
        exit(0);
    }
 


    c = fgetc(fptr1);
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        fputc(c, fptr2);
        c = fgetc(fptr1);
    }
  
    printf("\nContents copied to %s", filename);
  
    fclose(fptr1);
    fclose(fptr2);
    return 0;
}



}
```

It coppies full content from one file to another. I need to copy only strings that have `5` as the last character (3 column)

For example Data.txt looks like that:

```
Alex 10B 4
John 10A 3
Kate 10C 5
```

In file that I will create during execution has to be coppied only `Kate 10C 5` string. I've been trying for hours but I don't know how to do this. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end of each line there is a newline character, (`\n`) you can use that to read line by line and copy only the ones that you want:

```
FILE* dest = fopen("out.txt", "w+"); // supressed null check for simplicity

char buf[100];

char* char_to_find;

// parse line by line
while (fscanf(ptr, " %99[^\n]", buf) == 1){
     
    char_to_find = buf;
    
    // reach the end of the line
    while(*char_to_find){
        char_to_find++;
    }
    
    //move one back
    char_to_find--;
    
    // if it's 5 save, if not move on
    if(*char_to_find == '5' && *(char_to_find - 1) == ' '){
                    
        fputs(buf, dest);
    }
}
```

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/MJkUk_uQf)

Comment: I need to copy whole string where third == 5

Comment: @stack I added a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you! I've edited your code to have opportunity to create new file for copying, instead of constant `out.txt`.

Comment: I've posted full answer

Comment: @stack well done, I just made a working example, you can and shoud adapt the code to your needs and improve it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function call

`while (fscanf(ptr,"%*s %*s %s ",buf)==1)`

consumes the input from the input stream, so that it is no longer available for copying. You are only saving the contents of the last field, but all other data is lost.

I suggest that you read one line at a time into a memory buffer, by calling the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) in a loop. That way, you will process one line of input per loop iteration, and will be saving the contents of the entire line.

In every loop iteration, you can use [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) on this memory buffer to determine whether the third field has the desired value, and if it does, then you copy the entire line to the output file. Otherwise, you do nothing and proceed to the next line (i.e. the next loop iteration).

```
char line[100];

//process one line of input per loop iteration
while ( fgets( line, sizeof line, input_file ) != NULL )
{
    char third_field[20];

    if (
        //third field was successfully extracted
        sscanf( line, "%*s%*s%19s", third_field ) == 1

        &&

        //third field contains the string "5"
        strcmp( third_field, "5" ) == 0
    )
    {
        //copy entire line to output file
        fputs( line, output_file );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
  
int main()
{

    FILE* ptr = fopen("data.txt","r");
    char filename[100];
    if (ptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("no such file.");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Create a file \n");
    scanf("%s", filename);
  
 
    FILE* dest = fopen(filename, "w+"); // check for null like above
    



    char buf[100];
    
    char* char_to_find;
    
    while (fscanf(ptr,"%99[^\n] ", buf) == 1){
         
        char_to_find = buf;
        
        while(*char_to_find != 0){
            char_to_find++;
        }
        
        char_to_find--;
        
        if(*char_to_find == '5'){
            
            printf("%s\n", buf); // test ptint
            fputs(buf, dest);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that checking for space before 5 is iportant, otherwise 55 or 65 or whatever will also be saved. `if(*char_to_find == '5' && *(char_to_find - 1) == ' ')` unless you're sure that those are always single digit.